# Make Algorithm more efficient

Tags: c#, algorithm

Two (2 digit) numbers are written together, so they form one 4 digit number. This 4 digit number can be divided by the multiplication of this two numbers. The problem is that I have to find this numbers.

I wrote an algorithm and get 2 pair of these numbers.

1) 13 and 52, so 1352 can be divided by 13 * 52.

2) 17 and 34, so 1734 can be divided by 17 * 34.

My algorithm looks like this:

```
for (int i = 1010; i <= 9999; i++)
{
    int mult = (i / 100) * (i % 100);

    if ((i % 100) > 9 && i % mult == 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(i / 100 + " <--> " + i % 100);
    }
}
```

---

Edit: with this algorithm (based on mentallurg answer) I find this numbers a bit faster

```
for (int i = 10; i < 99; i++)
{
    for (int j = 10; j < 99; j++)
    {
        int mult = i * j;
        int num = i * 100 + j;

        if (num % mult == 0)
        {
           Console.WriteLine(i + " <--> " + j);
        }
    }
}
```

I am interested in how I can make this algorithm more efficient.

Comment: The first thing thing that popped to my mind is that if you already checked `13 * 52` and know it's `1352`, you don't need to check `52 * 13` to know it's *not* `5213`...

Comment: @ZoharPeled, yes but implementing this willn't make it slower? (because I have only two pairs of this kind of numbers )

Comment: If I increment i by 2 (i+=2) i get the same result, so maybe it is better to use it?

Comment: Check out [code review SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). Seems more fitting for this question.

Comment: This snippet of code should run almost instantly. Next time you should add an benchmark result to your question and what do you expect.

Comment: @JHBonarius Either SE sites should be fine.

Comment: Please give your question a more meaningful title; everyone's trying to "make algorithm more efficient".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is very efficient:

```
var query =
    from x in Enumerable.Range(10, 90)
    from n in Enumerable.Range(1, 10).TakeWhile(w => w * x < 100)
    let v = x * (100 + n)
    where v % (n * x * x) == 0
    select new { x, y = n * x };
```

It computes all possible first digits. It then computes all of the possible second digits that are multiples of the first digit that are greater than zero and less than 100. It then produces the a candidate value at checks if it is divisible by the product of both digits.

It gives both of the possible answers.

Here's the equivalent using `for` loops:

```
for (int x = 10; x <= 99; x++)
{
    for (int n = 1; x * n < 100; n++)
    {
        var j = x * n;
        int v = x * 100 + j;
        int d = x * j;
        if (v % d == 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(x + " <--> " + j);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are checking for example 1010, 1020, and so on, and not 1012 for example. what is the idea behind it?

Comment: @Alex - If I have the number `10` then to form a four digit number starting with `10` that is also divisible by ten I can only look at `1010`, `1020`, `1030`, ..., `1090`. There's no point in looking at `1012`.

Answer (score 1):

Supposed one of the pairs are a and b, and so the four digits number can be expressed as 100a + b. Do a little math

```
100a + b = m * a * b
```

Divided by a on both sides, we have

```
100 + b / a = m * b
```

We can conclude that

1. b can be divided by a, let's say (b == n * a);
2. b must be greater than a, since 101 is a prime. *And it cannot be 3/7/9 times of a, since 103/107/109 are also primes, but let’s neglect this to make the for loop simpler. This can be easily handled in the inner loop of the following code.*

So the for loop can be written like this

```
for (int a = 10; a < 50; a++)
{
    for (int n = 2; n * a < 100; n++)
    {
        if ((100 + n) % (n * a) == 0)
            Console.WriteLine(a + " " + n * a);
    }
}
```

The number of iteration of the loop is reduced to a few dozens, from almost 10 thousand.

Answer (score -1):

Use 2 nested cycles from 1 to 99 and you will avoid two division operations on each step.